# How could i get the content of a stored procedure using sql query

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the content (statements) of a stored procedure on databaseA  and in serverA,

I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use databaseA
go
sp_helptext 'YourProcedure'
go
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Routine_name, Routine_Definition
From Information_Schema.Routines
Where Routine_Name = "YourStoredProcedureName"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use DATABASE_NAME

select [name], [text]
from sysobjects SO join syscomments SC
on SO.id = SC.id
where xtype = 'P'
```